# String to DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion, string-formatting

I have a column of varchar type and it contains a lot of data (we are talking about millions of records). I select only the date columns, like this:

```
select Value from mytable where ISDATE(mytable.Value) = 1
```

and I want to convert all the values in the result to the format of `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt`

Note that the values are of many different formats.

How can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Do you know all of the possible date formats ahead of time?  I'd think you need to parse all the strings into an intermediate DATETIME object and then pull the string back out using your display format.

Comment: Why not convert dates from the UI instead consuming DB Server resources?

Comment: @Ron, what kind of UI are you talking about? I have millions of already stored date values unfortunately stored as varchars and I want to convert them to a unified format.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was a permanent conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(value as datetime), 101) + ' ' 
     + substring(convert(varchar(20), CAST(value as datetime), 9), 13, 5) 
     + ' ' + substring(convert(varchar(30), CAST(value as datetime), 9), 25, 2) As dateValue
FROM mytable 
WHERE ISDATE(mytable.Value) = 1
```

More on date formats for SQL SERVER

[SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Reason is that he needs it in "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"  Can you do you that without breaking day and time? Please, add your answer, if you can.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi You've deleted your comment? What about downvote? Can you make your point?

Comment: thank you, I figured out the remaining of the solution myself independently from your answer, which is not the same, but it's equivalent, of course. Thank you again.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad , you're welcome. Please, add you answer too as answer or in your question, so that others can see solution.

Comment: It is equivalent to yours, there is no difference between the idea behind my solution and yours, so, basically I would duplicate your answer, as I started to solve the AM/PM problem based on your initial answer. There is no point really to put in my answer, because there are no relevant differences.

Comment: I thought it would be good for others to see different solution, but if it's almost the same query, you can leave it this way :)